# Is this a common or flawed security practice?

Tags: node.js, security, networking, encryption, server

I would like user authentication to take place in the following way:

- User generates an encryption key and keeps it on their device. The key is then encrypted by their password.
- To create a new account, the user sends a public key and a signed message that says something like "new member". The server decrypts the message and verifies that the public keys match. It then creates a new account for the member.
- Any time the user interacts with the server, he signs a message with the private key stored on his or her device indicating his or her request. Perhaps the parameters for the request are also encrypted.

The server verifies that the user is in possession of the private key at each step. At no point is the private key communicated over the internet. The way I see it, this entire protocol could be run over GET requests with no security holes. The only security hole appears to be local storage of a user's key, but my implementation avoids this (hence the method which is derived here).

Now comes the real question. Are there any libraries set-up for this protocol that would make implementing it very easy? I'm looking for node and bower implementations. Most crypto libraries make you do something like this in 5-6 steps. That's adequate, but I'm wondering if this is actually a common method that I just haven't heard of.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're gaining over just doing GET requests over https with two-factor auth.  The two-factor auth will prove you are who you said you are (simlarly to your proposal).  The https will protect the transport using private key/public key technology (similarly to your proposal).  And, this is all standard tech.

Comment: In addition, SSL has already thought about things you perhaps haven't such as replay attacks and server impersonation attacks.

Comment: @jfriend00 The downside of SSL is that the client has no way to prove his identity - [almost nobody uses client certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48802/how-to-validate-a-client-certificate). And you can't exactly get a FOB to your users.

Comment: Uhh, just use two factor auth over SSL.  After establishing the SSL connection, just use two factor auth to prove your identify.  That is all you're proposal is really doing (showing that you must have two things a token and a password).  You are overthinking the use of SSL.  Use it to verify the identity of your server (something you aren't doing) and then use it to protect the transport from spying or replay.  Then, over that now-protected SSL connection, use two-factor auth to prove you are who you are.  This is exactly what SSL is for.

Comment: Just send the user's password over HTTPS. All the "public key and a signed message" does is essentially send a proxy for the password.

Comment: Yes you can get a FOB inthe form or any of several phone app. Ihave RSA, Authy and VIP Access.

Comment: You need to start with a security definition, what is being protected, from whom, what the value is and the capability level of the attacker.